# HttpPost Action get empty Model on button Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Scenario**

I have a master/Detail page with master data on top and detail data with loop in table format.

I want to get Id when a user clicks on button.

**Problem**

`HttpPost` action in called but with empty model. I want SaleId which is hiddenField, not all Fields are required

My **Models** are

```
// Sales is Master Model
public class sales
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "sale_id")]
    public long saleID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "orderDate")]
    public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
// This is Detail Model
public class salesDetail
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "sale_id")]
    public long saleID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "pkg_dur")]
    public int pkgdur { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "m_name")]
    public string mName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "price")]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}
// This is used to display data in view 
public class SalesMD
{
    public sales sale = new sales();
    public List<salesDetail> detail = new List<salesDetail>();
}
```

**View** is

```
   @model namespace.Models.SalesMD

  //For Showing Master Data
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.sale.saleID)
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.sale.Name)
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.sale.orderDate)

  // For Showing Detail Data in table form
  @foreach (var item in Model.detail)
   {
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mName)
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pkgdur) Month(s)
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
   }
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult SalesDetail(Models.SalesMD md)
```

(***here md is getting values with 0s and null***)
Remember: I only want SaleId which is hiddenField
I am Trying to get the saleId like that `md.sale.saleID` but it is Zero

Finally the rendered HTML of hidden field. It have the value

```
   <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field sale_id must be a number." 
     data-val-required="The sale_id field is required." id="sale_saleID" 
      name="sale.saleID" type="hidden" value="2">
```

When i am using

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult SalesDetail(long saleID)
```

it is generating exception

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'saleID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SalesDetail(Int64)' in 'MAK_ERP.Controllers.makAdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

**Solution**

> **Finally I solved** that by using **HTML.HiddenFor** instead of
>   **HTML.DisplayFor**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.DisplayFor`, is for displaying your Model properties in your View. It doesn't render an input in your View. So, obviously, the Model is null, because there's no data collected in your View and submitted to the Controller.

You need to use `Html.EditorFor` instead.

If you only need to post the Hidden input to your Controller, why are you trying to bind the posted data to your ViewModel? Just change your Action to this:

```
public ActionResult SalesDetail(long saleID)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that but i only need the Id which is a hiddenField

Answer (score 0):

You are either missing a form `@html.BeginForm(...)` or you have just not included the code here, and if you're only after the `saleID`, you need to use..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SalesDetail(long saleID)
```

Comment: i am using @html.beginForm.